# gin-swagger can not find schema type: "handler.component"

Tags: go, swagger, go-gin

I am trying to use a struct that I created and I use in my code as the parameter, but after running `swag init` I am getting the following error:

`ParseComment error in file /src/handler/handler.go :can not find schema type: "handler.component"`

My struct:

```golang
package types

// Component defines the structure of the json that user will send for a log search
// swagger:parameters component
type Component struct {
    // in: query
    // example: {"envID":"default", "podID":"log-gen-6d776dc797-bnbm9", "follow":false, "tail":5}
    EnvID  string `json:"envID"`  // The env-id
    PodID  string `json:"podID"`  // The podID
    Tail   int    `json:"tail"`   // Number of lines for tailing the logs
    Follow bool   `json:"follow"` // If the we want to follow the logs or not
    Site   string `json:"site"`   // The cluster/site which hosts the component --> local is pointing to the local cluster
}
```

My handler:

```golang
package handler

import (
    "src/types"
)

// FollowLogsSSE is ...
// @Summary Return logs
// @Accept  json
// @Produce  json
// @Param q query component true "{'envID':'default', 'podID':'log-gen-6d776dc797-bnbm9', 'follow':false, 'tail':5}"
// @Success 200 {object} string string
func FollowLogsSSE(comp types.Component) gin.HandlerFunc {
}
```

I also tried `// @Param q query types.component true "{'envID':'default', 'podID':'log-gen-6d776dc797-bnbm9', 'follow':false, 'tail':5}"` but I got the exact same error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `types.Component` (with capital C) and everything will work fine.

Some extra points:

- There is on need for any decorator, etc for the types and swagger will find the struct without a problem and also shows the comment for each field
- For defining a field as required you can add `binding:"required"` to that field:

```golang
    EnvID  string `json:"envID" binding:"required"` // The env-id: this can be an env that has created by the user or any other K8s namespace
```